# Windows Store - ApplicationDataCompositeValue Int32 value is null

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

In the following code I am able to access the int value of 1 using:

```
composite.ElementAt(1).Value
```

however when I try and access it using

```
composite["intVal"];
```

it is null.

The strange thing is it's not null for the other string value I have.

Why is it null when I try to access it using `composite["intVal"];` ?

```
        private void addCompositeValues()
        {
            ApplicationDataCompositeValue composite = new ApplicationDataCompositeValue();
            composite["strVal"] = "string";
            composite["intval"] = 1;
            ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["exampleCompositeSetting"] = composite;
        }

        private void readCompositeValues()
        {
            ApplicationDataCompositeValue composite = (ApplicationDataCompositeValue)ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["exampleCompositeSetting"];
            object strVal = composite["strVal"]; // "string"
            object strValKey = composite.ElementAt(0).Key; // "strVal"
            object strValValue = composite.ElementAt(0).Value; // "string"

            object intVal = composite["intVal"]; // null - why is this null?
            object intValKey = composite.ElementAt(1).Key; // "intVal"
            object intValValue = composite.ElementAt(1).Value; // 1
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you made a typo while writing the question I would assume the reason is the casing of `intVal`.

You're storing it as `intval` (lower case `v`):

```
composite["intval"] = 1;
```

And you're reading it as `intVal` (upper case `V`):

```
object intVal = composite["intVal"];
```

Value names are case sensitive.